Did classical philosophers see a happy ending to the story of humanity?
Philosophical and religious views about the end of the world are predominantly in the room of doom and gloom.
But did we have an exception, with more positive views on the future of humanity?

Plato writes in the Timaeus: ‘there have been and there will be a
great many destructions of humans’. Rather than understanding history
as headed toward a definitive, teleological end, Plato sees human
development as continually determined by various forms of world
catastrophe
Roman emperor Marcus Aurelius (121-180 CE) wrote about the end of the
world as part of his daily practice of philosophy: ‘Everything in
existence will quickly be changed: either it will be turned into
vapour, if the nature of the Universe is one, or it will be
scattered.’

https://psyche.co/ideas/how-the-ancient-philosophers-imagined-the-end-of-the-world

The conundrum is, if we talk about humanity the only happy end is no end at all, we keep striving as a species forever. Notwithstanding the physical problems it raises (heat death of the universe, etc), it logically follows that any philosopher who was concerned with the end of humanity was concerned with an unhappy one. The others simply didn't address the issue. Then there is a huge problem of interpretation: some might consider the christian eschatology, where all the righteous people receive eternal reward in heaven to be a happy one, some might beg to differ.

The idea of linear time with an "ending" dates to late antiquity and came from Christian thinkers like St. Augustin. Classical philosophers saw time as illusory (Parmenides), cyclic (Heraclitus, Stoics), relational (Aristotle), etc., so there was no "story" to end. Plato's view was similar to Heraclitus's, a chain of periodic  diacosmesis (creation) followed by ekpyrosis (destruction) of the universe, eternal return later picked up by Nietzsche, see Berchman, In the Glance of the Logos.

@Conifold - Thanks for the article on time. In physics time is the inverse of frequency. We count cycles using a clock to indicate linear time as elapsed time. Sigmund Freud had a paternalistic model where the psychotherapist takes money from the suffering person and tries to adjust their ego, their efforts to govern action in this world, to the realities of this world, and he called it the talking cure. He said the ego is doomed to suffer due to inability to sustain states of intense pleasure which biologically attenuate over time; inability to prevent aging/death; and harm caused by others.

"What if this is as good as it gets?"

You may look at Auguste Comte who triumphantly described the progress of Humanity through three stages:

Comte's stages were (1) the theological stage, (2) the metaphysical stage, and (3) the positive stage.

The Theological stage was seen from the perspective of 19th century France as preceding the Age of Enlightenment, in which man's place in society and society's restrictions upon man were referenced to God. Man blindly believed in whatever he was taught by his ancestors. He believed in supernatural power. Fetishism played a significant role during this time.
By the "Metaphysical" stage, Comte referred not to the Metaphysics of Aristotle or other ancient Greek philosophers. Rather, the idea was rooted in the problems of French society subsequent to the French Revolution of 1789. This Metaphysical stage involved the justification of universal rights as being on a vaunted higher plane than the authority of any human ruler to countermand, although said rights were not referenced to the sacred beyond mere metaphor. This stage is known as the stage of the investigation, because people started reasoning and questioning, although no solid evidence was laid. The stage of the investigation was the beginning of a world that questioned authority and religion.
In the Scientific (positive) stage, which came into being after the failure of the revolution and of Napoleon, people could find solutions to social problems and bring them into force despite the proclamations of human rights or prophecy of the will of God. Science started to answer questions in full stretch. In this regard, he was similar to Karl Marx and Jeremy Bentham. For its time, this idea of a Scientific stage was considered up-to-date, although, from a later standpoint, it is too derivative of classical physics and academic history.

Comte's law of three stages was one of the first theories of social evolutionism.

And from SEP:

For Comte, science is a “connaissance approchée”: it comes closer and closer to truth, without reaching it. There is no place for absolute truth, but neither are there higher standards for the fixation of belief. Comte is here quite close to Peirce in his famous 1877 paper.
The law of the three stages belongs to those grand philosophies of history elaborated in the 19th century, which now seem quite alien to us. The idea of progress of Humanity appears to us as the expression of an optimism that the events of the 20th century have done much to reduce.

What Comte called positivism became logical positivism/analytic philosophy in the 20th century and scientism in the 21st.
It is difficult for us in the 21st century to appreciate the science-euphoria of the 19th century — starting Dalton making the whole edifice from billiard balls — atoms — to Mendeleef organizing that nicely into a 2-D arrangement and finally the sunset of the materialist heyday with Thomson discovering the electron, Planck the black body effect and Einstein the photoelectric effect as the century turned.
Further the SEP talks of the "events of the 20th century" damping the enthusiasm for Progress of Humanity.  I guess the article needs to be updated to the 21st where we are trying hard to outdo the 20th.
If you see the emptiness of this outlook but still are drawn to evolution, there are Aurobindo (Hindu), Teilhard de Chardin (Christian), Marx (atheist) and of course Nietzsche — I teach you the superman.

So, these are "the good old days"?

@ScottRowe I guess you could say that the ol boys of the good old days thought that these would be the good new days

"The future ain't what it used to be." I guess I imagine the endless generations who huddled around fires and banged rocks together while dying of trivial ailments. Maybe things aren't so bad right now? At least we are here to see it.
